# TVS diode electrical parameters

Tags: esd, tvs

I am using below diode in my design to protect 3V3 lines:-

http://www.ibselectronics.com/ibsstore/datasheet/AZ5123-01F_Datasheet.pdf

On page 2 they have given :-

[image]

Also, they have given on same page :-

[image]

What is the meaning of this!! What is +-16KV & what is the 7V??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are saying two things.

Firstly, if testing the device (on its own) with an ESD gun conforming to IEC 61000-4-2 then it will survive a 16 kV discharge test. It's listed in the absolute maximum ratings section and this is generally what that section defines. It doesn't tell you what it will clamp to but it'll be in the order of tens of volts

Further down they are saying that it will clamp a 6kV discharge to typically 7V when used with the same ESD gun. This gives you some confidence about performing in-circuit testing and what sort of voltage levels you may witness when doing ESD testing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this :- "This gives you some confidence about performing in-circuit testing and what sort of voltage levels you may witness when doing ESD testing."

Comment: @Rishi when you have your circuit built with components all fitted you *may* want to perform ESD gun tests on that sub-assembly and if you do you need to ensure that your ESD gun is set to 6kV or less to prevent clamp voltages greater than 7V.